# "Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page" while executing Protractor tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular, protractor

I try to execute some Protractor tests on a web application that consists of both Angular and non-angular components.
My code looks like so:

```
describe("Test Name", function() {
  it("Test case", function() {
    // first execute steps on a non-Angular component
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    // some test steps

    // then execute tests on an Angular component, which opens in a new browser tab
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
    // some more test steps
    });
});
```

The problem is that after the above test is run, the browser launches and immedietaly closes with the following error:

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test
>   involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643 for details"

When I remove `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` from the code, the steps for the non-Angular component are executed successfully, then the Angular component of the application is opened in the new browser tab, nothing happens for 10 seconds (no steps are executed) and the browser closes with the following error:

> Failed: Wait timed out after 10007ms

Comment: Is your protractor version >6.0, if not do you have `SELEMIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` declared in your conf?

Comment: @mariobrosbb you should probably add the tests steps as well to help us help you :-) Sounds to me like an asynchronous problem. Maybe try and use the `done` pattern or chain these with async\await or promises.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably account for asynchronous code and wait for promises to resolve. Also, add [Jasmine's `done` parameter](https://angular.io/guide/testing#jasmine-done) to the test function to let selenium know when the test is finished.

Another thing that might cause this is activating `waitForAngularEnabled` before you're actually in an angular page. I suggest you prefix that call with a call to check that something on the page **already got loaded** so you know angular is ready to be hooked by protractor before waiting for angular activities.

It's important to note that protractor waits for the next action after `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` to trigger the check, relying on that might make the problem unclear if sometime later someone changes the code.

```ts
describe("Test Name", function() {
  it("Test case", function(done) {
    // first execute steps on a non-Angular component
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
      .then(() => /* step1 */)
      .then(() => /* step2 */)
      // ...
      //  this one is very important to make sure
      // we're in an angular page 
      .then(() => ensurePageTitleIsVisible())
      .then(() => browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true))
      .then(() => done())
      .catch((err) => done.fail(err));
  });
});

function ensurePageTitleIsVisible() {
  return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(PAGE_TITLE_SELECTOR), jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL, 'Title does not exist after timeout');
}
```

This might give you a better error message as well.

and of course, you can do the same with async \ await syntax.

```ts
describe("Test Name", function() {
  it("Test case", function(done) {
    try {
      // first execute steps on a non-Angular component
      await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
      await step1();
      await step2();
      // ...
      await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
      done();
    } catch(err) {
      done.fail(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Basically, your problem happens because you continue with the test steps before the `browser.waitForAngularEnabled` function actually finishes.

Comment: I believe after `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` is set protractor will only begin monitoring the stability of the angular page once there is a new interaction on the page, triggering the change detection, so it is fine (even advisable) to set `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` while on a non-angular page provided your next action takes you to an angular page. I think you are correct about it being an asynchronous issue, OP may have disabled the control flow without realizing

Comment: @DublinDev cool! didn't know that :-) . But if something only works with a specific case, I usually prefer not to use it. If I write a test that runs `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` since the next action takes me to an angular page, and a month from now someone adds a new line before the navigation that checks something else, it might break without the other guy understanding what happened. So I think that I prefer being sure I'm actually in an angular page before doing that. it will keep the code clearer and less breakable for later changes

Comment: @DublinDev  added a comment to the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` when interacting with non angular ui  since it makes protractor not to wait for Angular promises

and `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` followed by `browser.waitForAngular();` when interacting with angular ui

Comment: `browser.ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated `browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` is the required replacement currently